# Trie vs HashMap, which one to use - Interview question

Tags: hashmap, trie

The task - 
Given a collection of **text** files (assume list of files), you need to design a data structure. The time complexcity for construct the data structure is not important, the only thing importatn is the time complexity (access time) for the follow three methods giving the data structure implementation is up and running:

`find(String word)` - returns all the files that contains the given word.

`findAnd(String word1, String word2)` - returns all the files that contains both words.

`findOr(String word1, String word2)` - returns all the files that contains at least one of the words.

I am having difficulties to decide between two approaches:

**First approach**

Just insert all the words to an `hashMap<string word, list containsFiles>`, and each word (key) will get the appropriate value (list of files). When accessing the data structure, after getting the list (in O(1) time in average case) all I need to do is generate the correct answer by the method name and return it.

**Second approach**

Use `hashMap<Character ch, Item item>` where item itself contains an hashMap

```
class Item{
   hashMap<Character ch, Item item> map;
   list<file> containsFiles;
}
//assume file class looks as follow
class File{
   String name;
   Date creationDate;
   File file
}
```

In other words, inplement sort of a Trie using HashMap. And also here, after getting the list (in O(L) where L is the length of the key) all I need to do is generate the correct answer by the method name and return it.

Design wise - I tend to choose the second approach because I dont like the idea of mapping potentially large amount of words to list of files, and also I dont like the dependecy between my design to Java hashMap implementation (how collision in my case will affect performance).

Please tell me, what is the correct approach between the two both from time and space complexicty aspects **and WHY? - Very important for me to understand**. Is there any better solution you would suggest?

Comment: I don't see how a trie, which is meant to look by prefix, would be of help here, if all you need to do is search by whole words. You could mention Aho-Corasick as an alternative, but it becomes useful when you need to check many words at once, not just one and/or two.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned above that trie might benefit here because the independecy of the hash function mapping exists in the hashMap. Probably at some point (because it might be a huge map) the get method of the hashMap wont be in constant time but log(n) time. where in the Trie case the get will always be O(L) as mentioned above. Am i right?

Comment: Consider a scenerio where each file contains the entire Oxford dictionary (about 600K words), and lets say you have about 100K files. Would you still be using hashMap?

Comment: Absolutely. Hash maps are always O(1) average, no matter the number of entries. I'd use a hash map of lists, because the same word could appear in more than one file. All you need is enough memory.